# URL Rewriting multiple folders to one folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-routing, iirf

I'm using [IIRF](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx) on IIS6/Server03 with an MVC app in the root of the server and a virtual directory for the wordpress blog/cms. I'd ideally like the urls as follows...

- domain.com/
- domain.com/wpcategory/ -> rewritten from domain.com/blog/wpcategory/
- domain.com/wpcategory/wparticle/  -> rewritten from domain.com/blog/wpcategory/article/

Thanks to the ISAPI Plugin I can use modrewrite esque code...

```
## REGIONAL GUIDES ##
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /guides /guides/index.php [L]
```

But bar writing guides to guides etc I'm struggling to work out what or even if I can actually do that or if it needs to be in a subfolder domain.com/wp/wpcategory/article (which currently works fine.
Essentially looking to rewrite the base to the root of the site without stuffing MVC... Fun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for [ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(wpcategory/.*)$ /blog/$1 [NC,L]
```